# Como Poner Contraseña a una solución o proyecto en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, visual-studio-2015

Cómo puedo poner contraseña en un proyecto en C#, VB o visual studio para proteger el código fuente? Existe alguna forma de encriptar mi codigo?

Comment: Cuáles son los resultados de tu investigación? Qué has leído? Qué palabras has buscado en google? 
La forma en que la pregunta está escrita, la hace muy sujeta a opinión. Yo podría decir "Tienes que agregar seguridad a tu pc". Si es en red "restringir el acceso al control de versiones". Si es a nivel de .dll, por si alguien descompila el código, entonces "ofuscar el código".

Comment: Tienes razon, he leido de ofuscar el codigo , exactamente deseo que no se pueda modificar el codigo de ninguna forma , se que tienes muchas opciones en seguridad interna en tu pc , pero queria saber si se podria directamente desde el VS 2015

Comment: [Skater .NET Free Obfuscator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rustemsoft.SkaterNETFreeObfuscator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe una forma de establecer una contraseña al proyecto o solución desde Visual Studio. Sin embargo, en cuestión de seguridad, hay varias cosas que puedes hacer.

1-. Si el código está en tu pc, puedes establecer una contraseña en ella para que nadie más que tú tenga acceso.

2-. Si el código está en un repositorio público, o vas a distribuir tu aplicación y tus .dll están ahí, puedes ofuscar tu código con herramientas para este propósito. Si buscas en google la frase ".net obfuscator", tendrás muchas herramientas para escoger.

3-. Si el código está en un sistema de control de versiones, entonces, puedes limitar el acceso al mismo mediante contraseñas o sólo permitir mediante vpn.

4-. Si todo lo demás falla, siempre puedes contar con WinRar para comprimir con contraseña.

Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Si tocara irse por las seguridad que enlista y muchas mas, muchas gracias por tu ayuda